# Spark parquet uneven blocksize

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2, parquet

I inspected the output parquet file of a spark job that always beaks, because of `Out of Memory Errors`.
I use `Spark 1.6.0` on `Cloudera 5.13.1`

I noticed that the parquet row group size is uneven.
The first and the last row group are huge. The rest is really small...

Shortened output from parquet-tools `RC = row count`, `TS = total size`:

```
row group 1:                RC:5740100 TS:566954562 OFFSET:4  
row group 2:                RC:33769 TS:2904145 OFFSET:117971092  
row group 3:                RC:31822 TS:2772650 OFFSET:118905225  
row group 4:                RC:29854 TS:2704127 OFFSET:119793188  
row group 5:                RC:28050 TS:2356729 OFFSET:120660675  
row group 6:                RC:26507 TS:2111983 OFFSET:121406541  
row group 7:                RC:25143 TS:1967731 OFFSET:122069351  
row group 8:                RC:23876 TS:1991238 OFFSET:122682160  
row group 9:                RC:22584 TS:2069463 OFFSET:123303246  
row group 10:               RC:21225 TS:1955748 OFFSET:123960700  
row group 11:               RC:19960 TS:1931889 OFFSET:124575333  
row group 12:               RC:18806 TS:1725871 OFFSET:125132862  
row group 13:               RC:17719 TS:1653309 OFFSET:125668057  
row group 14:               RC:1617743 TS:157973949 OFFSET:134217728
```

Is this a known bug? How can I set the parquet block size (row group size) in Spark?

**EDIT:**
What the Spark application does is: It reads a big AVRO file, then distributes the rows by two partition keys (using `distribute by <part_keys>` in the select) and then writes a parquet file for each partition using:
`DF.write.partitionBy(<part_keys>).parquet(<path>)`

Comment: I have used 13 Executors. Is it possible, that the node local rows go into the big row group and the remote reads from each executor go into a seperate row group?

Comment: were you able to fix your issue or find a workaround ?

Comment: No i was not able to find a workaround yet

Answer (score 2):

Your RDD could be unevenly partitioned. The number of rows in each block is related to the size of the different partition of your RDD.

When a RDD is created, each partition contains roughly the same amount of data (due to the [HashPartitioner](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/HashPartitioner.html)). After the processing of the Spark job, one partition could contain more data than another , maybe a filter transformation removed more rows from one partition than from another. The partitions can be rebalanced calling [repartition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#repartition(int,%20scala.math.Ordering)) before writing the parquet file.

**EDIT:** if the problem is not related to the partitions, maybe reducing the size of the row groups could help:

```scala
sc.hadoopConfiguration.setInt( "parquet.block.size", blockSize )
```

Comment: Please see my edit. The RDD is repartitioned before the write operation.

Comment: you could try to change the block size (see my edit), but I don't know if this will solve the out of memory problem

Comment: This setting works on a development cluster with some sample data. If I use it with my real application, it does not affect anything unfortunately...
Is this configuration overridden from somewhere?

Comment: Could you check what happens if you call [repartition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#repartition(int)) *before* you create the DataFrameWriter (`DF.repartition(13).write.partitionBy...`)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a known bug for this : 
[PARQUET-1337](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1337)